# multi tabbed javascript application with URL support using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am designing a multi-tabbed or multi-paged javascript web application that allows the URL to change depending on which tab you selected.

The best example I have seen is done by Zendesk

[image]

By calling it multi-tabbed, am I describing it correctly?

The tabs can be closed or opened depending on what is clicked.

How to create something like this using ReactJS? If there is a good tutorial, I am also happy to read through it.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with react router. If you are not familiar with react router go to the [react router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router) github page and check out the tutorials and docs. Here's an example of what it may look like to get you going.

**Routes**

```
<Route path="/" component={Application}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="tabs" component={TabLayout}>
        <Route path="1" component={Tab1} />
        <Route path="2" component={Tab2} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} isNotFound/>
</Route>
```

**Tab Layout**

```
/* This is the layout for your tabs. Using react router to link to different tabs.
When the route changes props.children will be updated to reflect the current
route. You can add active classes to your tabs. Reference the react-router docs to 
see how to do that
*/

import {Link} from 'react-router';

const TabLayout = props => {
    return (
        <section className="tab-container">
            <div className="tabs">
                <Link to="/tabs/1">Tab 1</Link>
                <Link to="/tabs/2">Tab 2</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};
```

**Tab 1 and tab 2 look like this**

```
// Tab1 and Tab2 are just react components. For simplicity I am just using
// a stateless component.

const Tab1 = props => {
    return (
        <h1>Tab 1</h1>
    );
};
```